# Как удалить символы из строковой переменной?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Приветствую всех. Получаю адрес текущей страницы

```
var A = window.location.pathname;
```

в которой, к примеру, **/razdel/razdel/page/12345/**
Подскажите, пожайлуста, каким образом откинуть все, что следует за предпоследним слэшом. В PHP прошелся бы прег_сплитом и было бы мне счастье в массиве, а тут прям проблема. Получается только все слеши откидывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A.replace(/(.*)\/.*\//, '$1');
```

Дополнение к другому ответу

```
var text = '/razdel/razdel/page/12345/'.split('/').slice(0,-2).join('/');
```

Comment: Спасибо, Роман.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поделить строку методом .split в массив и выбирать нужные элементы потом...

Comment: Спасибо. Этот способ мне ближе. Разобрался со сплитом. Один в один как explode на php. Как-то яву раньше стороной обходил. Использовал по минимуму. Надо бы почитать и покодить на ней по более. 21 век все-таки. Пора и ajax осваивать. Сейчас даже стремно стало за такой вопрос))

Comment: @leonoff может быть через split будет даже быстрее. 

        var text = '/razdel/razdel/page/12345/'.split('/').slice(0,-2);

Comment: @leonoff, "ява" никакого отношения к JavaScript не имеет. Не путайте, а то читать не про тот язык будете :)

Comment: @klopp, ждал подобного ответа :)

Comment: @lampa, еще раз спасибо. Я так и сделал, за исключением того, что ввел еще одну переменную, хотя можно было все в одной строчке нарисовать. Говорят, плохая привычка - лишние переменные. Буду исправляться :)